# Flutter Login type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, http, laravel-api, flutter-http

This is my file user_model.dart

```
class UserModel {
  int id, nik;
  String password, token;

  UserModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.nik,
      required this.password,
      required this.token});

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
        id: int.parse(json['id']),
        nik: int.parse(json['nik']),
        password: json['password'],
        token: json['token']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'nik': nik,
      'password': password,
      'token': token,
    };
  }
}
```

This is my file auth_service.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:techsolution/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AuthService {
  Uri url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.28:8000/api/login');

  Future<UserModel> login({
    int nik = 0,
    String password = '',
  }) async {
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    var body = jsonEncode({
      'nik': nik,
      'password': password,
    });

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(data['user']);
      user.token = data['token'];

      return user;
    } else {
      if (response.statusCode == 422) {
        throw Exception('Required Data');
      }
      throw Exception('Data is Wrong');
    }
  }
}
```

This is my file auth_provider.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:techsolution/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:techsolution/service/auth_service.dart';

class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late UserModel _user;

  UserModel get user => _user;
  set user(UserModel user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> login({
    int nik = 0, 
    String password = '',
  }) async {
    try {
      UserModel user = await AuthService().login(nik: nik, password: password);
      _user = user;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my view the login.dart

```
AuthProvider authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    handleLogin() async {
      if (await authProvider.login(
          nik: int.parse(nikController.text),
          password: passwordController.text)) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        if (context.mounted) return;
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    }
```

I have tried to login several times, but in my terminal it produces type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String', I wonder why it is like this. This code has been erroring for 3 days and I tried many times but I still can't find a way to solve the problem. I was confused and couldn't sleep for 3 days

Comment: On which line does it happen? Can you add your JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase User credential `uid` is returned as `String`

Modify your Model likewise

```
class UserModel {
  String id; 
  int nik;
  String password, token;

...

factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
        id: json['id'],
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I think it has an error in the nik or password

Answer (score 0):

The error it self said that any of your int data which are not subtype of String means your id or nik data are String but you gave type int. So according to error you need to change the data type of id or nik from int to String;

```
class UserModel {
  int nik;
  String id,password, token;

  UserModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.nik,
      required this.password,
      required this.token});

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
        id: int.parse(json['id']),
        nik: int.parse(json['nik']),
        password: json['password'],
        token: json['token']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'nik': nik,
      'password': password,
      'token': token,
    };
  }
}
```

Or

```
class UserModel {
  int id;
  String nik, password, token;

  UserModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.nik,
      required this.password,
      required this.token});

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserModel(
        id: int.parse(json['id']),
        nik: int.parse(json['nik']),
        password: json['password'],
        token: json['token']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'nik': nik,
      'password': password,
      'token': token,
    };
  }
}
```

Above one of the code will work for you and get output as you expected...